# What does it mean when a C++ file has .cpp.hpp at the end of the filename?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

This question has nothing to with why C++ has header files, or what extensions are commonly used for header files.

Why would a file have *both* ".cpp" and ".hpp" in the name?

For example,

```
example.cpp.hpp
```

Sorry if the answer seems obvious or easily searched, but I've looked through a number of different search engines and can't find anything.

Comment: I don't believe you bothered to read my question. Nothing on that page has filename that ends in ".cpp.hpp"

Comment: It's possible this is a file for template definitions, which need to be in the same TU. I've never seen anyone use that as an extension, so it's the only thing I can think of apart from something adding the .cpp extension automatically.

Comment: Maybe someone did not understand that `.hpp` means "C++ header", so he wanted to point out with the .cpp that the file is written in C++

Comment: @user4759923 I'm a little hesitant to believe that since there are plenty of other files that he wrote with a .hpp extension and the fact that this guy is on the level of a principal engineer and has been writing C++ professionally for more than a few decades.

Comment: @LightyearBuzz Well, it's simply silly dong such, or asking about. Kick the _principal engineer_ in their ass, since they did something obviously wrong.

Comment: Maybe it was a source file some times ago, and then it was converted to a header

Comment: Perhaps you should try ask the person that created the file.

Comment: IMO, certainly a mistake, probably caused by misuse of an IDE.  E.g., have the IDE open a wizard for a "new class" or something and enter a filename, including `.cpp`, not noticing that the IDE template that opened is for a header file.  Or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is a almost certainly a header file, because of the `.hpp` extension. (It could be a source file, no one knows, the extension doesn't mean anything).

Note that only `.hpp` is the extension, not `.cpp.hpp`. The actual file name is `example.cpp`. There can only be one extension for any given file.

Why would anyone do that? Here's a theory:

The default option on Windows (I think) is to hide file extensions. The person maybe tried to change the extension, by renaming the file. But because the actual extension was hidden, he added `.cpp` to the actual filename, and so the file became `example.cpp.hpp`. Because the `.hpp` part was hidden, the person thought that the file had the correct extension, when it hadn't.

Comment: By convention, a header would have a .hpp extension (.cpp could be a header if you wanted it to be). However, .cpp.hpp isn't exactly a widely-used convention in the first place.

Comment: @chris Really? I though that was the convention.. Is it `.cc`?

Comment: One file having the full .cpp.hpp is not a convention I have seen. .cc, .cpp, and .hpp all are.

Comment: @chris I know, I haven't said that either. Can you please tell me the line where I said that so that I can change it because I can't find it. Thanks. (Or maybe do you mean my comment, I was referring to `.cpp`, sorry)

Comment: Just the definitive "Your file is a header file, because of the .hpp extension.", since the main requirement is simply being a text file regardless of extension.

Comment: @chris Oh, I see. Thanks :)